# Ordered probit in stan

Tags: r, bayesian, stan

I'm just learning stan and have a few questions. I am trying to do an ordered probit model in stan. I have a couple of questions. First, the model below throws an error message `Stan model does not contain samples.` What does that mean and how do I go about fixing it?

Secondly, how do I tell stan the constraints I want to identify the model? As of now, it's unidentified location-wise. I'd like to tell stan to set one of the `tau`s to be a specific value (0, for example) but am uncertain how to do that.

```
data{
  int<lower=1> N; // number of obs
  int<lower=3> J; // number of categories
  int<lower=2> K; // num of predictors
  int y[N]; // outcome var 
  matrix[N, K] x; // predictor vars 
}
parameters{
  ordered[J-1] tau; // thresholds
  vector[K] beta; // beta coefficients 
}
model{
  vector[J] theta;
  vector[N] xB;
  beta ~ normal(0, 100);
  xB <- x*beta;
  for(n in 1:N){
    theta[1] <- 1 - Phi(xB[n] - tau[1]);
    for(j in 2:J-1)
      theta[j] <- Phi(xB[n]-tau[j-1]) - Phi(xB[n]-tau[j]);
    theta[J] <- Phi(xB[n] - tau[J-1]);
    y[n] ~ categorical(theta);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's the R code I called:

```
stan_data <- list(N = dim(insurance)[1], # 1000
                  K = dim(insurance)[2], #5
                  J = length(table(insurance$spend)), #3
                  y = insurance$spend, # vector of length N where each element is 0, 1, or 2
                  x = my_xmatrix) # matrix of dim 1000, 5

mcmc_oprobit <- stan(file="stan/oprobit.stan",
                     data = stan_data)
```

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might try the  [Stan Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/stan-users). That's the method the devs seem to prefer for answering questions.

Comment: @RichardErickson - thanks. Doesn't look like I have posting privileges there.

Comment: You'll need to join the group. https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1067205?hl=en

Comment: The `Stan model does not contain samples` message is from R and usually means you did not pass the data to Stan correctly. We need your R code to say why that is, although there should have been more to the error message prior to that.

Comment: @BenGoodrich - see my edits. The only error that R prints is the one I wrote (though it returns 4 times, one for each chain). Is there a default setting I need to change to see more error messages or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I call,

`N <- 1000
J <- 3L
K <- 2L
y <- sample(0:2, N, replace = TRUE)
x <- matrix(rnorm(2 * N), N , 2)
mcmc_oprobit <- stan(file="oprobit.stan")`

then I ultimately get

`Informational Message: The current Metropolis proposal is about to be rejected because of the following issue:
Exception thrown at line 22:
stan::math::categorical_log: Number of categories is 0, but must be between (1, 3)
If this warning occurs sporadically, such as for highly constrained variable types like covariance matrices, then the sampler is fine,
but if this warning occurs often then your model may be either severely ill-conditioned or misspecified.`

In which case, the problem can be overcome by recoding your outcome variable to be 1, 2, or 3 rather than 0, 1, or 2. But that raises the question of why you are not seeing that Informational Message? What platform, GUI, and version number of RStan are you using?

Comment: ah, so stan doesn't like nonpositive categories. This works now. I am running rstan on Windows (through RStudio). rstan version 2.7.0-1 (which is the latest on CRAN, I believe).

Comment: Also, how would I go about doing the second part of my question? Namely, how to set one of the `tau`s to some specified value (0, for example) in order to identify the model?

Comment: It is identified by the likelihood if `x` does not contain a column of ones. That is the easiest route to identification in an ordinal model.